# Android App keep crashing at run time and import issue

Tags: android

My application keeps generating "unfortunately app has stopped working" on my device. I've looked at my code and can't see any errors but I believe I may have identified what my logcat files are complaining about.

Here is my logcat:

```
    09-06 14:38:20.974: D/AndroidRuntime(28710): Shutting down VM
09-06 14:38:20.974: W/dalvikvm(28710): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41573700)
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bluetooth.le/com.example.bluetooth.le.DeviceScanActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.bluetooth.le.DeviceScanActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.bluetooth.le-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.bluetooth.le-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.bluetooth.le.DeviceScanActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.bluetooth.le-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.bluetooth.le-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
09-06 14:38:20.974: E/AndroidRuntime(28710):    ... 11 more
```

I have a strong feeling that it is going to complaining about this import:

```
import com.example.bluetooth.le.R;
```

I think for the import to stop generating that error my applications name should be in place of the .le. So in my case it would read:

```
import com.example.bluetooth.samplebletest.R;
```

But I get an error telling me that the import cannot be resolved.

Is my crash related to this import? How can I fix it?

Comment: plz post your manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

1. Your Android project declares `com.example.bluetooth.le` as a `library`. **Project Properties->Android->Library+**
2. Android Dependencies are being exported. **Project Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export**
3. The activities you use in your project are in your project manifest.
4. Finally validate that the Activity you're trying to create is really included in the library apk not just a jar that is being used to resolve during compile time.